# WebRTC OPUS codec : Minimum Bandwidth for good audio

Tags: webrtc, html5-audio, audio-streaming, opus

In my WebRTC application, OPUS codec has been used to compress the audio stream and I was wondering what is the minimum viable bandwidth that should be allocated for audio stream without jitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I tested a few hundred Kbps (bits, not bytes), approximately 300-400Kbps should be enough for good audio quality, not only voice, but music too. But more important is the network latency, which should be under 20-25ms.

For decent voice audio a tenth (30-40Kbps) should be enough. But this is for one peer only. The latency can be much higher but you'll hear small skips now and then, which should acceptable for conversations.

Comment: 300-400 :) You'd wish :)

Comment: For videos 256kbps is pretty good number, 300-400kbps seems to be certain value for good audio quality. I was looking for lower bound as my application needs to send/receive streams with multiple users and I need to minimize the bandwidth usage.

Comment: Then it depends. If you want to optimize it for voice, you can get away with a tenth of that value.

Comment: Yes, the use case for my app is to have conversation between peers. So, I guess 30-40 kbps will do good enough for the above use case.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But this is for one peer only. The bandwidth minimum requirements depends on the number of peers too. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For Opus voice encoding, mono 16KHz sample rate:

- 6Kbps is a minimum, when voice is still recognizible
- 16Kbps is a medium - good enough
- 32Kbps is a maximum - you wont see big difference if encode at higher bitrate (higher than 32)